# Trying to set mouseover on the node but the label of the node triggers multiple events

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, d3.js, dom-events

I am trying to set up a simple `mouseover` and `mouseout` event on a D3 node. All works fine the only issue is when I have a label on the node. When I `mouseover` the node I get the event, but then when I `mouseover` the label of that same node, it causes that `mouseover` event to trigger again without me ever leaving the node, like I moused in and moused out of the node itself. My UPDATED code:

```
            var isInside = function (node:any, target:any) {
                for (; node != null; node = node.parentNode) {
                    if (node === target[0][0].outerHTML) {
                            return true;
                    }
                }
            };


          svg.selectAll("g.node").on("mouseover", function(object: any) {
            var hoveredNode = d3.select(this);
            var event = d3["event"]["relatedTarget"];

            if (!isInside(event, hoveredNode)) {
                  // I only want to call the function below if the mouse sits inside the node itself, not when it hovers over the label
                  ctrl.onNodeHoverSelectedLocal(object);
            }
        });

    // this code runs when I hover over the label of the any node. It acts as a seperate part of the node. When I hover here and hover off I don't want the console.log above to run. Only when I come completely off the node itself.
            svg.selectAll("g.label").on("mouseover", function (object: any) {
                        var hoveredNode = d3.select(this);
                });
```

How can I select the label of the hovered upon node, and then compare the node itself to the label so that I only get the `console.log("hover")` one time for each `mouseover` instead of every time I `mouseover` and `mouseout` the label  of the node.

The DOM tree for the node looks like this:

```
 <g class="nodes">
   <g class="node">
      <rec rx="3" ry="3"></rect>
      <g class="label">
        <g transform="translate(#, #)">
           <text>
             <tspan>Node Label Here</tspan>
           </text>
        </g>
      </g>  
    </g>
   </g>
```

Open to other solutions as well.

Comment: I believe you have to stop propagation. Can you create a minimal fiddle or plunkr, so I can edit your code?

Comment: That is really all the code I have, along with a general d3 node with a label. Wouldn't some sort of event propogation have to be put on the label then? That doesn't seem to work either. Propogating would stop the event from moving to the label to the parent node. I can try to add a plunkr if this doesn't help

Comment: The problem is that the label acts as if you're hovering on and off the node

Comment: The "mouseout" of the g.node triggers when I hover over the label..???

Comment: A Plunker would be nice, because we can give you a tested solution.

Comment: I typically would put it in a plunker but this sits inside a huge angular component. It would be overly complicated to build a plunker with it. I'm just curious as to why the label acts as seperate from the node? I would imagine that would be the case for any d3 node with a label inside it. I updated my code above a little bit. Thanks

Comment: Are the labels inside the nodes in the DOM tree?

Comment: Yeah the labels sit inside, I updated my post to show what the DOM tree looks like for one node. So the label does sit within the node but it acts as if it is different from it in the case of a hover.

Comment: So, actually this is the normal behaviour! Have a look here, "eloquent javascript": http://eloquentjavascript.net/14_event.html#p_H543iFvHsm

Comment: Interesting, so the final working code then to prevent the behavior I am getting is to get the event on the mouseover and mouseout, and then in eloquent javascript its getting the "p", but in my case I already have the g.node when the mouseover takes effect. so inside my function above I just need to get the event and call that "inside" function from the link. Does that seem right?

Comment: I'm not able to transfer that code over. D3 operates differently in that it gives different results for the target and the node.parentNode. I don't ever access the return statement because the parentNode and the target are never the same. I have to try and get the outerHTML of the target which is then a string and compare it to the node element itself.  I'm really just trying to get the hover of the label and the node to be one, like it should be.

Comment: But this is the problem: if you set a handler to the parent, and the children are in different positions, each children will fire the handler separately (or independently).

Comment: Yeah the problem seems to be that the label is independent of the node. There would have to be a handler on the g.node itself to activate the correct classes and functionality when the mouse is over the node. Wouldn't there? Do you see a solution for this? I'm honestly lost here. I see the issue and the what its doing but I'm not able to find a solution.